# showing facebook page news feed on a website

Tags: php, facebook

I used a javascript I found on the facebook developers site. It used to show my pages newfeed on the website and had a like button for people to join the page, it worked great up until around the time they made a change to the pages layout (about 1 month ago), which unfortunately broke it.

The script I am using is http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US

you can see it in action:
http://fullmount.co.nz/index.php?main_page=news

I am wondering if, there is something simple that could be change dint he script to get it working again, or if there is another script I could use instead that works with the newer pages format?

I am a php wizard but a js amateur so I haven't even really looked at the code, I just knew it used to work.

Comment: you wanted something like this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ ?

Comment: actually the script was working fine, the issue was there hadn't been any posts in so long that the script wasn't picking up the old posts.